# Displaying price in cents

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, currency, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to display a price in cents (`99¢`) instead of dollars (`$0.99`) using NSNumberFormatter and a locale.

This code turns a price of 99 cents into the string: `$0.99`. Is there a way to get NSNumberFormatter to try to use smaller/cent denominations, when possible, instead?

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedPriceString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: I am confused about what you want to do, you have already converted the amount from `$` to `¢`

Comment: did you try using [numberFormatter setMultiplier:@100];

Comment: @Aladin I'm trying to localize the IAP pricing info I receive from Apple, so I can't assume I know the currency I'm receiving.

Comment: @Steve I can't make assumptions about how the localized currency works :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no easy and general-purpose way to do this. I think you just have to handle it on a case-by-case basis. If you want to localize your app for an international audience, but expect many of your customers to be from the US, you can do something like what I did:

```
if priceString == "$0.99" && NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as? String == "US" {
    priceString = "99¢"
}
```

Comment: I think you're right and this is a helpful solution :)